# AssertJ + verify items returned in subList contains string as will be present in any of the list items

Tags: assertj

I have requirement, say in my response I get the results in list as "brisbane, australia", "sydney, australia" and "melbourne, australia". Now I need to test that, the results contains "sydney" in any of the three results.

```
softAssertions.assertThat(resultArrayList.subList(0, 3))
              .extracting("title")
              .as("Title match")
              .containsAny(expectedTitle);
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [allSatisfy](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#allSatisfy-java.util.function.Consumer-).

```
softAssertions.assertThat(resultArrayList.subList(0, 3))
          .extracting("title")
          .as("Title match")
          // assuming titles are String, use contains String assertion
          .allSatisfy(cities -> cities.contains("sydney"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Joel Costigliola. When I try to use as suggested above . I see that contains is getting ignored.Kindly suggest what is that I am doing wrong. softAssertions.assertThat(resultArrayList.subList(0, 3)) .extracting("title") .as("Title match") .allSatisfy(cities -> cities.toString().contains("sydney"));

Comment: I was assuming `cities` was a String but it looks it is not since you had to call toString. What is the type of the title field you extract ?

Could you provide the complete code with the test case you are running, it's a bit difficult to help when having only partial information.